# Can I use a function such as strtolower() in the echo statement in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert the variable name to all lower case, in an echo statement. For example:

```
$categories = array('1'=>'Holiday')

foreach ($categories as $categoryId => $category) {
   echo "<div class=\"container\"> <a href=\"category.php?categoryId=$categoryId\">
         <img src=\"images/categories/strtolower($category).jpg\" alt=\"holiday turkey\" class=\"image\">
         <div class=\"overlay\"> <div class=\"text\">$category</div> </div> </a> </div> ";}
```

I want to convert the variable name to all lowercase, so I can get the picture. I tried just changing the name of the image to Holiday.jpg but I wanted to know if this is possible...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a function within an echo call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406441/how-to-run-a-function-within-an-echo-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$categories = array('1'=>'Holiday')

foreach ($categories as $categoryId => $category) {
   echo "<div class='container'><a href='category.php?categoryId=$categoryId'>
         <img src='images/categories/".strtolower($category).".jpg' alt='holiday turkey' class='image'>
         <div class='overlay'> <div class='text'>$category</div> </div> </a> </div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it like this:

```
foreach ($categories as $categoryId => $category) {
    echo "<div class=\"container\"> <a href=\"category.php?categoryId=$categoryId\">
         <img src=\"images/categories/" . strtolower($category) . ".jpg\" alt=\"holiday turkey\" class=\"image\">
         <div class=\"overlay\"> <div class=\"text\">$category</div> </div> </a> </div> ";
}
```